# Google Webmaster Tools not showing links to my site: "data not available"

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks

Three days ago I received a notice from Google Webmaster Tools about unnatural inbound links, but my GWT does not show any links to my site. How can I check which unnatural links GWT means?

Answer (score 4):

Google has announced that they will try to give more example links in cases when they send 
out unnatural links warnings.  Its disappointing to hear that you get no guidance in Webmaster Tools.

Here are some third party tools that list links to your site:

- [Bing Webmaster Tools Link Explorer](https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/diagnostics/link/explorer)
- [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/)
- [Google Analytics Referral Traffic Report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1247839?hl=en)
- [MajesticSEO](http://www.majesticseo.com/)
- [SEOProfiler](http://www.seoprofiler.com/)
- [Moz](http://moz.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You can check your website backlinks with a tool like [Ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com). You can easily identify bad links to your website by reading [this webpage](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66356) from Google.